# Problem with making a histogram

Tags: histograms

I have written code that simulates a M/M/1 queue system.

```
μ = 2; λ = 1.5; n = 5000;
t = 0; served = 0; sList = {}; QList = {};
tOutList = {}; tOutList[[0]] = 0;
Do[X = -Log[Random[]]/λ;
   Y = -Log[Random[]]/μ;
   t = t + X;
   tOut = Max[tOutList[[i - 1]], t] + Y;
   AppendTo[tOutList, tOut];
   AppendTo[sList, tOut - t];
   While[tOutList[[served + 1]] < t,
       served = served + 1;
       AppendTo[QList, {tOutList[[served]], i - 1 - served}
       ];
   ];
   AppendTo[QList, {t, i - served}];
   ,{i, 1, n}];
```

I tried to use a result from the above code to show the time spent by customers into the system a in histogram.

```
s = 0;
h = 
  Histogram[sList, 
    HistogramScale -> 1,
    HistogramCategories -> Table[i, {i, 0, 30, 0.25}]];
p = Plot[(μ - λ)Exp[-(μ - λ)*x], {x, 0, 10}];
Show[h, p]
```

But I get the following error From `Show`:

> Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[Histogram[{0.4337989554392946`, 2.3556653158517125`,<<

How can I fix this?

Edit: My version of Mathematica is v6

Comment: [`HistogramScale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Histograms/ref/HistogramScale.html) and [`HistogramCategories`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Histograms/ref/HistogramCategories.html) are no longer valid options for `Histogram` since version 7 of MMA. What version are you using? Where did you get the code? If you remove them, then Show will work fine; it is failing now because Histogram fails and does not return a graphics object.

Comment: @MarcoB It may be for the very old Histograms package (pre-v7).

Comment: I forget to mention that my version of mathematica is 6

Comment: @ParisL if you evaluate the `Histogram` snippet alone, do you get a correct plot, or does that fail?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, when i select "Evaluate in cells" i do get a correct plot

Comment: @ParisL and the same for `p`? That also plots correctly when evaluated independently?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, also
    `Plot[(μ - λ)Exp[-(μ - λ)*x], {x, 0, 10}]`
works just fine alone

Comment: I think i found the solution. I needed to load the `<< Histograms`;` package

Comment: Glad that you found that out, but your previous answers confuse me. How could you have got a correct histogram plotted if you didn't have the package loaded at the time? Oh well..